# How do I create a link in the ChicletSlicer visualization to a local file?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

Good afternoon, Geniuses!
In the Chicletsli visualization, there is a traffic light filter using png images.
Uploaded them to Dropbox and got the link.
Here is an example: **https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qmy4w05hkkxsvg/yel.png?raw=1**
Everything works fine with this, but Internet access is limited on a working computer, so i have to create a link to a local disk.
I try in every way, but it doesn't work:
Here is an example of attempts:

1. D:\Хазратхон\Учеба\power bi\Bob\Исходники\Картинки\yel.png
2. D:/Хазратхон/Учеба/power bi/Bob/Исходники/Картинки/yel.png
3. D:/Хазратхон/Учеба/power bi/Bob/Исходники/Картинки/yel.png?raw=1
4. I tried to open the image through the browser and substitute a link from there  file:///D:/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BD/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0/power%20bi/Bob/%D0%98%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8/yel.png

Nothing works.